# xts - keep calculation of columns intact, even though some columns might be missing

Tags: r, xts

I am setting up a "decision-map" in xts. The result of below code generates following:

```
              dec.1 dec.2 dec.3 dec.4     Master.dec
2017-01-01      2     2     2    2          2
2017-02-02      3     3     3    3          3
2017-03-03      0     0     0    0          0
```

There will always exist minimum one of these columns (dec.1 -> dec.4), but it will be unknown whether it is 1,2,3, or 4 columns (dec.1 -> dec.4).

In the original solution the decision columns will be spread out through the xts-sheet so I will not be able to use column number as identifiers.

**Question:**

In column "Master.dec" I calculate based on the left-side columns (dec.1 - dec.4), whereof sometimes it will be 1,2,3, or 4 decicion columns. Is there a way to keep the calculation done in "Master.dec" intact and working, despite if 1 to 3 of the decision columns would not be present ?

**To reproduce the problem I encounter:**

1) run the complete script

2) delete one column: xts1$dec.1 <- NULL

3) run only the section 2 of the script (2.add a rules system)
...you will get the error:

Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [0]

**Note!** The solution should be able to have removed 1-3 decision columns, there will always be one decision column but unknown which ones.

```
    # dependent libraries
library(matrixStats)
library(xts)
#############################################
# 1. Create the xts from a data.frame base
#############################################
# creates a dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-02", "2017-03-03"), 
              other.1 = c(1998, 1999, 2000),
              dec.1 = c(2, 3, 0), 
              other.2 = c(58, 54, 32),
              other.3 = c(12, 3, 27),
              dec.2 = c(2, 3, 0),
              dec.3 = c(2, 3, 0),
              other.4 = c(2, 5, 27),
              dec.4 = c(2, 3, 0)
)

# transforms the column date to date-format
df1 = transform(df1,date=as.Date(as.character(date),format='%Y-%m-%d'))  
# creates the xts, based on the dataframe df1
xts1 <- xts(df1[,-1],order.by = df1$date)

#############################################
# 2.Add a rule system:
# if all "dec"-columns are 2, add value 2 in master.dec
# if all "dec"-columns are 3, add value 3 in master.dec
# if all "dec"-columns are 0, (or any other combination then above) add   value 0 in master.dec
#############################################
xts1$m.dec <- ifelse(rowSds(xts1)==0,rowMins(xts1),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `xts` object is essentially just an indexed `matrix`, you could try calculating the row wise standard deviation. If the result is `0` (ie. all values are the same), then you assign the `rowMin` (or `max`, whichever you prefer) to your new column, otherwise `0`.

An efficient and concise solution can be found using the `matrixStats` package:

```
library(matrixStats)
xts1$m.dec <- ifelse(rowSds(xts1)==0,rowMins(xts1),0)
#           dec.1 dec.2 dec.3 dec.4 m.dec
#2017-01-01     2     2     2     2     2
#2017-02-02     3     3     3     3     3
#2017-03-03     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: - Mtoto, your suggestion is brilliant. Very clear, structured and to the point of what I need. It is a very good base. What is missing is:
1) Deleting a dec.X column throws an error: xts1$dec.2 <- NULL:
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [0].
2) The possiblity of having the dec.X spread out with other columns in between (where it could be possible that those columns actuall would have a 0/2/3 but the matrixStats function should not react. (only on dec.X columns).

Comment: im not sure i get what the problem is, you can always specify the columns beforehand, `xts1[,cols]`

Comment: I will update the code in the example to clarify my comments.

Comment: - Code updated. I have added some other columns to show more how end result would look like. - Still, the dec.X will be produced based on other variables, e.g. either 1,2,3, or 4 dec.X, therefor I cannot refer them to their names since matrixStats would complain if the name does not exist. -Further on, I cannot refer to the column number since the dec.X might show up in different column number.

Comment: I think you have answered the question with a very good solution, so I will set it to complete. I will open another question to define the other pieces of the question.

Comment: Ok, you might want to rephrase and reduce this question though because it is not entirely clear and might be difficult for future readers to understand that you are simply after code to check whether all elements in one row are the same and put an if else condition on top of it.